# How to use groups in testNG

Tags: selenium, testng

I am implementing groups in the testng test suite.When I run my testng suite suite,it runs only the 'FireFox' test and when I put the  tag in 'Firefox' test 
            it runs the 'IE' test.Kindly let me know what can be the reason for this??

```
         <groups>
         <run>
         <include = "smoke"/>
         </run>
         </groups>
                  <classes>

                          <class name = "com.asw.beginner.tests.NewTest"/>
                 </classes>
         </test>

         <test name = "FireFox" allow-return-values = "true">
         <parameter name = "browser" value = "FF"/>


         <classes>
         <class name = "com.asw.beginner.tests.NewTest"/>
         </classes>
        </test>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your test as following:

```
public class Test1 {
  @Test(groups = { "functest" })
  public void testMethod1() {
  }

  @Test(groups = {"functest", "checkintest"} )
  public void testMethod2() {
  }

  @Test(groups = { "checkintest" })
  public void testMethod3() {
  }
}
```

Then you can use xml file as following

```
<test name="Test1">
  <groups>
    <run>
      <include name="functest"/>
    </run>
  </groups>
  <classes>
    <class name="example1.Test1"/>
  </classes>
</test>
```

> Above test will only run the method with group functest.

You can read more about testng from [Official testng documatation](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups)

Comment: I have a similar testng .xml file.The only difference is i have 2 <test> nodes.I have observed that when the <group> node is placed in test1 the test2 node is executed.Is there any valid explanation for this??

Comment: Did above solution solved your problem? If you want to run group test you need to include group node in the testng file.

Comment: Apologies for late reply...yes the solution has worked.Thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

Following is example java code

> ```
> import org.testng.Assert; import org.testng.annotations.Test;
>
> public class GroupTestExample {    String message = ".com";    MessageUtil messageUtil = new MessageUtil(message);
>
>    @Test(groups = { "functest", "checkintest" })
>        public void testPrintMessage() {
>       System.out.println("Inside testPrintMessage()");
>       message = ".com";
>       Assert.assertEquals(message, messageUtil.printMessage());    }
>
>    @Test(groups = { "checkintest" })
>        public void testSalutationMessage() {
>       System.out.println("Inside testSalutationMessage()");
>       message = "tutorialspoint" + ".com";
>       Assert.assertEquals(message, messageUtil.salutationMessage());    }
>
>    @Test(groups = { "functest" })
>        public void testingExitMessage() {
>       System.out.println("Inside testExitMessage()");
>       message = "www." + "tutorialspoint"+".com";
>       Assert.assertEquals(message, messageUtil.exitMessage());    }   }
> ```

following is Testng.xml file

> ```
>   <groups>
>      <run>
>         <include name = "functest" />
>      </run>
>   </groups>
>
>   <classes>
>      <class name = "GroupTestExample" />
>   </classes>
>    </test> </suite>
> ```